# What is the difference between an Active animated rigid body and a Passive rigid body?

Tags: physics

In the Rigid-body settings, there are two options, *Active* and *Passive*.

My question is, What exactly does the *Passive* setting do? how is it different than *Animated Active*?
(I know what *Active* and *Passive* are,
just not what the difference between *Active Animated* and *Passive Animated* is)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This might be a [good read..](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation)

Comment: @iKlsR the link is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They act the same but have a very different purpose. Passive Animated just updates the objects during the simulation. Active Animated is used to key-framed the initial momentum

> animate the location or rotation of an Active physics object as well as the Animated checkbox. When the curve on the Animated property switches to disabled, the physics engine takes over using the object's last known location, rotation and velocities.

Quoted from: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2012/Documentation#Animation

Comment: the page is not found.

Answer (score 3):

*Active* objects are the core part of the physics simulation, with dynamic movement, gravity, etc. By checking *Active*, you are essentially telling the Physics simulator that those objects should experience forces, and it has to figure out where they go over the course of the simulation.

*Passive* objects, on the other hand, are fixed in place--are static. For the purposes of the simulation, they essentially act as rigid-bodied, static, collision objects. The *Animated* option allows you to control its motion with keyframes, but it still does not experience the forces modeled on *Active* objects.

For example, if you're making a simulation of a ball falling onto a table, the ball would be an *Active* object, since it is affected by gravity, whereas the table would be *Passive*, since it is fixed in place.

Comment: Why not only have Active, with an option for animated? what is different about passive from an animated active?

Comment: @gandalf3 Passive animated and Active animated, to the best of my knowledge, do the same things, but the internal calculations Blender uses are different.

Comment: They act the same but have a very different purpose. _Passive Animated_ just updates the objects during the simulation. _Active Animated_ is used to key-framed the initial momentum (see quote in my answer).

Comment: @Aldrik I get it.. thanks. accepting answer.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one.