# Settings to fill an open container with objects

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to create a natural arrangement of rubber thimbles in a jar.  What is the easiest method of doing this?

I've tried various settings with the jar being passive and using the various collision types like box, cylinder and mesh but none seem to work.

I tried dropping the thimbles into the jar but they either stop early and spill over or go through the jar! Is it better to use some sort of particle distribution? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use rigid body physics to do this, make sure of the following:

- All modifiers that you want to affect the simulation are applied
- The jar has thickness
- The jar is set to *Mesh* collision type to allow objects inside of it
- You may also want to enable *Split impulse* in *Scene > Rigid body world* to prevent intersecting objects flying apart at high speed.

To arrange the thimble objects above the jar you could use the [*Randomize Transform*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Advanced/Randomize_Transform) tool (<kbd>Space</kbd>*> Randomize Transform*)

Once you have simulated the objects falling into the container and you want to remove the physics but keep the location/rotation for a specific frame, you can do this by:

1. Select the objects you want to bake into posistion
2. Press *Bake to keyframes* in *3D view > Tool shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) > Rigid body tools* and set the *Start* and *End* frames to the frame you want to keep:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>. This will remove the rigid body physics settings from all selected objects, and add a single keyframe on the specified frame.
4. You can then remove this keyframe (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you expand this answer a little bit? I'm having trouble figuring out how to toss the animation of the physics simulation to keep just the static conclusion; I don't understand the last sentence of [this](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Using_GE).

Comment: @ajwood That page is talking about using BGE physics. See [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2122/599) for getting rid of the physics settings