# Using a particle system to fill up a container

Tags: particles

I want to use a particle system to fill a container. The particles are solid objects and not liquid. I just want a container to look like it was filled naturally, and not like a grid. It would be quicker to set up a particle system to do this than to manipulate tons of separate meshes individually. I'm not sure if this can be done in blender, but any help with this would be nice. I also need this to work with the cycles rendering engine.

Comment: why couldn't you just use a rigid body simulation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5213/599

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that post, gandalf3. That solves my problem