# How to make an object from basic volumes?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to 3d model and I want to create an object from basic volumes like spheres, cylinders, cubes, etc. For instance, I want to make a cube by fitting speheres in. Is there an automatic way of doing this in Blender or any other program?

**Edit details:** Your answers were so helpful. In addition, what I'm really trying to do is fill an irregular form with other irregular forms. For example, let's say, a
house (a cube with a pyramid on top of it) filled with little bottles (like little cylinders). (It's for a 3D printing project). Is this possible to do?

[image: Blender image]

Comment: Could you provide some images of result you are expecting?

Comment: So instead of an 8-vertex cube, you want the same volume filled with spheres?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really automatic but this can be done with the array modifier. Take your object that you want to make a cube out of and then apply three array modifiers. The result:
[image]

Going from here we can fill more complex things with the Boolean modifier. Take the mesh you want to fill with stuff and enclose it in the arrayed object. It will look something like this:
[image]

Then we use the Boolean modifier to cut out the shape. Giving this:
[image]

From here we apply the stack. It't not perfect / ideal / fast, but hopefully this is enough to get you somewhere until someone else has a better idea.

Final:[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Particle system - Volume Grid

For a quick approximation, you could duplicate an object with a particle system.

Select the sphere (cube, cylinder..) add a new Emit particle system that emits from Volume with Grid option enabled.

Then pick your object (in this case a little sphere) in the Render panel of the system like in the following picture:

[image]

You may have to adjust the grid resolution/object scale in order to fit them properly.

[image]

If you are looking for something more physically accurate than a simple grid, I think the only way I know at the moment is running a simulation.

You can have a look for example at: [Settings to fill an open container with objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5213/settings-to-fill-an-open-container-with-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ***dupliverts*** to do it. 
[image]

In *Edit Mode* subdivide your base object with <kbd>W</kbd>-->Subdivide (try to make the even mesh division). In *Object Mode* parent the object you want to duplicate with the base object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Object* (both objects should have the origin points placed in the same position and transformations applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Select the base object, go to *Object* header-->*Duplication* panel and set its type to *Verts* or *Faces*. Play with their settings. Scale the parented object for different duplicates' size.
[image]

To convert the duplicates to meshes press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
[image]