# Choose when a rigid body starts

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

When do I choose when a rigid body activates? I don't want it do start on its default 1st frame.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5100/599

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your concrete situation, there are multiple possibilities, such as the "Start Deactivated" checkbox, or you can keyframe the "Dynamic" checkbox