# What is the correct python code for pressing "I" and selecting LocRotScale?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I have already did a dummy test and all the rest of my code works. The only thing that fails is calling `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type = 'LocRotScale')`, which is what appears if you press I and doing it manually. The error I am getting is:

> File "D:\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in
>   **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw) TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "location" not found in
>   ('Location', 'Rotation', 'Scaling', 'BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot',
>   'LocRotScale', 'BUILTIN_KSI_LocScale', 'BUILTIN_KSI_RotScale',
>   'BUILTIN_KSI_DeltaLocation', 'BUILTIN_KSI_DeltaRotation',
>   'BUILTIN_KSI_DeltaScal)

The idea of my script is simple, there are 8 coordinates in a list that I want to loop through and apply each coordinate to a cube.

Pseudo code would be:

1. Frame_set the current frame on the timeline so starting frame would be at 0
2. I would take the coordinate[i] in the list and apply it to the cube
3. I would then key the location of the cube for animation
4. update the current_frame by =+ 4 each time. S0 frame 0, 4, 8... would be the keyframes.

All other steps works, if I comment out step number 3 I would see my cube moving from 1 location to the other, I just need to know how to key each location for animation!

My code is below:

```
current_frame = 0

for i in range( 0, len( selected_loc ) ): # selcted_loc contains 8 xyz vectors 

    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_set( current_frame )
    moving_object.location = selected_loc[i] #moving_object is just a cube

    #bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type = 'location') #line that fails

    current_frame += 4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should avoid `ops` functions and use the object's attributes and method to achieve your goal. (Ops is slow and can even be context dependant.)

To insert a location keyframe, use the [`keyframe_insert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) method of `bpy_struct`s with `data_path` parameter set to `location`.

Use the same method for scale, setting the `data_path` to `scale`.

In order to keyframe the rotation, you need to know the rotation mode. An objects `rotation_mode` can either be set to `QUATERNION` or `EULER`. The respective parameter values for the `data_path` parameter are `rotation_quaternion` or `rotation_euler`.

Below is a fully working example, given there is an object named *Cube*.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

selected_loc = [mathutils.Vector((x, 0, abs(x-5))) for x in range(8)]
moving_object = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

for i, loc in enumerate(selected_loc):
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_set(i * 4 + 1)
    moving_object.location = loc
    moving_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'location')
    if moving_object.rotation_mode == "QUATERNION":
        moving_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'rotation_quaternion')
    else:
        moving_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'rotation_euler')
    moving_object.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'scale')
```