# Creating Hydrogen Orbitals with Blende

Tags: python, animation, mesh, mathematics

I want to create a 3D Animation of a hydrogen orbital using the mesh.math addon. Therefore I wrote a short python code.

```
#Repositorys
from scipy.special import sph_harm
import cmath

#Variables
l = 1
m = 0
#v and u mesh variables (v from 0 to 2*pi and u from 0 to pi)


#Variables for linear combination
l2 = 2
m2 = 0
t = 0 

#Calculate linear combination
x = abs(sph_harm(m, l, v, u)  + sph_harm(m2, l2, v, u) * cmath.exp(-t*1j))  * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
y = abs(sph_harm(m, l, v, u)  + sph_harm(m2, l2, v, u) * cmath.exp(-t*1j)) * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
z = abs(sph_harm(m, l, v, u)  + sph_harm(m2, l2, v, u) * cmath.exp(-t*1j)) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
```

Now I want this to create a plot. And even an animation by changing t from 0 to 2*pi. To be honest I have no idea how Blender works so I would really appreciate your support.

Comment: Hi. So which specific part of this are you having difficulty with?

Comment: This question is rather vague for stackexchange standards. Check out [creating objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61893/30849) and [adding keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114513/what-is-the-correct-python-code-for-pressing-i-and-selecting-locrotscale/114522#114522).