# How to animate characters sliding?

Tags: animation

So I know how to animate using bones, I created some simple animations with human, however I want to try animating human on rollerblades. I've got no problem with making key frames for bones, however using rollerblades give character a momentum and they should slide.
I can't figure out how to keyframe the model sliding. Even though I animate bones, then move the whole rig to other location when I hit insert keyframes location+rotation the model still stays still.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any tutorial I could use for that?

Comment: When you moved the whole rig, did you do it in object mode or in pose mode? The "correct" way should be having a "main" bone which is directly or indirectly parent to all the other bones: that main bone should be used to animate all the character slide in pose mode.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/how-can-i-add-motion-to-a-rigid-body. This is a very usefull one, as you won't have to animate the sliding itself

Answer (score 0):

I would create an Empty and in Object mode click the Armature then the Empty and hit CTRL + P and set parent to object. Now when you move the empty, the whole object should move. You can get fancy and create a curve for the path and have the empty follow the path for the animation. I can attach screen shots or a .blend file if that's helpful.