# How to zoom in on a video clip with Python?

Tags: python, image-sequence

How to zoom in on a video clip with Python? I would like to zoom in "dynamically" starting from first frame and ending on last one.

I am using a sequencer to add image sequences like that:

```
seq = S.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
    name="Input",
    filepath=str(file_path),
    channel=image_chan,
    frame_start=1,
    )
seq.frame_final_duration = 100
```

I have tried to use a TRANSFORM effect but that gives mi only a "static" zoom for all frames.

```
eff = S.sequence_editor.sequences.new_effect(
    name="Transform",
    type="TRANSFORM",
    channel=4,
    frame_start=1,
    frame_end=seq_prev.frame_final_end,
    seq1=seq
    )
eff.use_uniform_scale = True
eff.scale_start_x = 0.5
eff.scale_start_y = 0.5
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133962/how-to-use-keyframes-and-the-python-api-programmatically