# initial velocity for a rigid body simulation: a ball rolling on a skew plane

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I can do a falling torus onto a plane, but I wanna have a modification:
a ball moving upwards on a skewed plane and then slowing and increasing the velocity
in the opposite direction as would physics suggest.
My question is: how do I give the ball an initial velocity?

Comment: so the ball needs to have physics from the beginning except it's going upwards?

Comment: @moonboots mostly yes. It should just have an initial velocity so no violation of physics occurs as it moves upwards the plane. I just do not know ho do I give it this initial velocity. I expect Blender then correctly and automatically gives it the opposite velocity (smoothly) in the opposite direction.

Comment: @moonboots What do you mean by "have physics" ? "obey physics" or "have initial velocity" instead of physics ?

Comment: at the beginning you could animate your object with the Rigid Body > Settings > Animate option that you can keyframe, but it will be animation, not physics, then disable this option, keyframe, and let the physics act on the object

Comment: @moonboots I have found the 2 buttons in Mass Dynamic and Animated, but I do not know how to use them. I'm a beginner and not familiar with the "keyframe" concept. Perhaps you could give me some hints to begin with. This specific question of mine is hard to seek in google which I would consult in other case.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5102/29586

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be another solution but I don't know it. So what you could do is:

- Give your object a *Rigid Body > Type > Active*, create your slope, *Type > Passive*.
- Put your object on the bottom, make sure it doesn't come across the surface, give your object a keyframe (<kbd>i</kbd>) *> Location, Rotation and Scale*, enable the *Rigid Body > Animated* option and give it a keyframe as well (put your mouse cursor over the option and press <kbd>i</kbd>):

[image]

- Several frames later, move the cube a bit, create a second keyframe for your object, then disable the *Animated* option and keyframe again:

[image]

- If the initial momentum is strong enough, it should work fine:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's going on here and sounds correct. Could you provide me with a .blend file ?

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer

Comment: Good. Now I just want to make it moving. Where do I enable it as in your last picture ? There is missing the |> button at the bottom.

Comment: spacebar to play, shift left arrow to go to frame 0

Comment: My cube falls down on the left without moving upwards to the right whenever I change something. Which parameter do I have wrong here ?

Comment: I don't know, maybe make sure that the cube doesn't touch the surface of the slope, if it still doesn't work, share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please see here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=9B6svB8n" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9B6svB8n/) I wanna move the cube more to the right, where can I change this ?

Comment: as I said, make sure that the cube doesn't touch the surface of the slope, it's the problem here, the cube goes through the surface at frame 0 and 5

Comment: Right it works now. But when I press the "G" key for Grab and then press mouse the cube is not in the position I put it right now but in a previous one. How can I fix it ?

Comment: delete the keyframes you've created and re-keyframe correctly

Comment: And yet, how can I create the horizontal green line between the 2 yellow dots indicating the seconds ? What this line means, when connecting the two points ? May it have a different color from green ?

Comment: it means that,- there are no transformations between keyframe 1 and 2

Comment: Where can I set this line to Green ? I have created an Orange one and the cube stays at rest.

Comment: oh ok you must be talking about the line that means that it has calculated the physics simulation, anyway you don't have to care about these lines

Comment: Sorry to continue asking do you mind? Here, the cube doesn't move at all, why? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=7JzSY8Lr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/7JzSY8Lr/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116165/discussion-between-moonboots-and-user3357120).