# How to make particles not go partially through plane?

Tags: particles, collision

I have a bunch of cards shooting out of a box with an emitter. I have rigid and collision on the collection of cards and the plane but when the cards hit the plane they go through it about halfway. and they won't fall over and lay flat. I've attached 2 pictures to help explain. The first 1 is as they are falling and the second is when they have all landed. How do I make it so they don't go through the plane and how do I make them fall over flat?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Afaik, rigid body simulations and particle simulations don't work together. So, this behaves purely like a particle sim. - That's why they are reacting/colliding only with their center point (particle) and the floor. You could increase the radius of that, but this won't do you much good, because then the cards would be floating in an invisible sphere. I'd recommend to go full rigid body and use forces to push the cards around. But it might be a bit tricky to get them to behave the way you want. (Hence, only a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Appreciate the response. Ill try that.

Comment: So I started doing your suggestion, while it is a little trickier it seems to be fixing the issue. But now some of the cards are coming out of the side of the box. I have rigid passive on the box. Any thoughts.

Comment: Maybe the box has not enough geometry to calculate the collisions with the cards. By the way, what Collision Shape have you set for the box? The default "Convex Hull" or "Mesh"? Try "Mesh". And I would set the cards to "Box" if they have some thickness instead of being simple planes.

Comment: Great suggestions by Gordon! You can also animate the initial ejection from the box using keyframes and then let the simulation take over. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/how-can-i-add-motion-to-a-rigid-body