# Simulations Rigid Bodies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a problem with my animation. I have two objects and I have already made an animation for the first one - it's falling down and bouncing - I made it manually. Then I want another object to fall on the first one and I want to use a rigid body simulation, but then something is really wrong and then the second object is not falling at all or moving somewhere else without any reason. I have tried applying scale, what should I do?

Comment: hello could you please share your file or show some screenshots?

Comment: Yes, is there a way to do it here? Or I coud just send you the file?

Comment: remove all the useless object and share the file here (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijEwKYO8A7nOEn2b9youg8zW4FTeeL5P/view @moonboots that's the blend file

Comment: So I am trying to make the tiny ball fall on the shoe at 230 frame but I don't know how

Comment: what tiny ball, what is its name?

Comment: sphere.003 ;) but you are late man ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i assume, you want to use sphere.003:

first, you should always apply scale if you use that object in a simulation: (do for shoe + sphere)

[image]

second: turn off animated on your sphere (because animated means: does not participate in rigid body simulation but will be animated manually by keyframes)

third: change collision shape to mesh for shoe:

[image]

else it won't fall properly on the shoe.

[image]

---

How to start rigid body animation from a frame:

set keyframe on checked "animated" one frame before it should start:

[image]

one frame later set keyframe on "unchecked":

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Applying scale only messed up the materials on the object, but the ball in not falling down anyway. How to make it start falling at 230 frames? It only falls if I make a new ball and start it on the first frame, then when I make any changes is completely stuck where it was.

Comment: Then you can scale your texture as well with the mapping texture node. Change the begin animation to frame 1. then start the animation, you can change it back later to 9.

Comment: no, It doesn't work

Comment: ok, it worked!!! So what I was doing wrong was applying the scale once, but I have to do it before every change - now - it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: But I still don't know how to start the rigid body simulation from a specific frame.

Comment: I want the ball to start falling at 230 frame, after the shoe is on the ground already.

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Select the object you want to have the rigid body. Open the physics tab and click the option that says "Rigid Body" and your object should use rigid body physics.

[image: Where to find the rigid body option]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: I did that and it's not working, and I don't know why.

Comment: Make sure the first dropdown is set to active and not passive. (Under the "Type" dropdown, right at the top)

Comment: Under the scene properties tab, (It looks like a water drop with two circles) Make sure both gravity and rigid body world are turned on.

Comment: it's checked. I tried both passive and active - nothing works.