# Activate physics by keyframe

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'd like to have a group of debris fall from a ceiling onto the floor, but not have them drop all at the same time. Is there a way to set a keyframe that dictates when the object enters the simulation? For example, object 1 starts falling on frame 0, object 2 on frame 5, object 3 on frame 24, etc.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between an Active animated rigid body and a Passive rigid body?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1552/599) and [How can I add motion to an object](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5100/599)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can keyframe the *Animated* checkbox by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

When *Animated* is enabled, the rigid body will be controlled with the animation system. When it is disabled, the rigid body will be controlled by the rigid body simulator.

Comment: So can I set keyframes on this checkbox? Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Justin Yes. When it is enabled, the object will not be controlled by the physics simulator.

Comment: How do you apply this to a large number of objects at the same keyframe?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise If the objects don't have any other conflicting keyframes, then Ctrl L > *Animation data* can be used to copy keyframes.

Comment: Im wondering what the use is than, if its animated it does not habe the physics. How can we have both worlds or is this not possible?

Comment: @RomboutVersluijs Not quite sure what you mean by "best of both worlds".. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps this helps? http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1552/599

Comment: Well i meant, it having physics but still be able to adjust the rotation. I want casino chips falling. I used particle emitter for creation added rigid bodies. They fall but dont rotate, so i tried animate in rigid body. I need research it better perhaps.

Comment: @RomboutVersluijs Individually animating in a rotation for each chip sounds like overkill (unless you need tight control over the result). Perhaps as a workaround you could have  them bounce off of a collision object before entering the camera frame to impart some random-ish movement?