# How do i start the rigid body dynamic in the keyframe i want?

Tags: animation, add-on, camera, video, rigid-body-simulation

I’ve been trying to animate a blowing skull, but, when i try to add the active rigid body dynamic, it stars from keyframe 1, when what i want is to start it in the keyframe 267.

Comment: [Rigid Body Physics activating Later?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74004/rigid-body-physics-activating-later)

Answer (score 1):

Go to frame 266.  Select your rigid body.  In properties/rigid body/physics/settings, check Animated and keyframe it.  Go to frame 267.  Uncheck Animated and keyframe it.