# keyframe multiple active objects

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I want to keyframe multiple duplicate objects created from a active rigid object. I have created keyframes for each duplicate object at different frames of timeline, lets say at frame 10, 50, 90, etc. When the animation is played all duplicate objects appeared at frame 1, instead of appearing at their respective frames i.e. 10, 50, 90, etc.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activate physics by keyframe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8483/activate-physics-by-keyframe)

Comment: No this isn't answer to my question. I want to place the objects at particular location at specific frames and let them fall freely through rigid body physics.

Answer (score 1):

When you duplicate object, I think, you keep linked Animation Data. So if objects share same animation data, you can not create different animations for objects. If that so, click Object -> Relations -> Make Single user -> Object Animation

[image]

If you want to duplicate the animation data when duplicating objects, make sure that this checkbox is checked:

[image]

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but, the problem isn't solved. All duplicate objects are appearing at frame 1.

Comment: After you separated animation data, did you rebuild animations?

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: I have also attached .blend file for reference

Comment: Now, I'm understood your question. Here is the answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8483/activate-physics-by-keyframe