# Having rigid bodies sliding off an animated object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to create an animation in which an object is lifted from the ground and several smaller objects slide from on top of it and drop to the ground.

Is there any possible way of doing this in Blender currently using physics? In other words, can I have rigid bodies slide down from animated objects? Any strategies/hacks are welcome!

Comment: Did you try anything? It should work with RigidBodies with some friction value...

Comment: I was always under the impression that animated objects could not participate in rigid body simulations! How cool that this turns out to be wrong (at least for passive objects).

Comment: @Antti This is true for Active objects as well. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1552/599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible.

Simply make your animated object a passive rigid body with *Animated* enabled:

[image]

Then make the objects you want to slide around into *Active* rigid bodies.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even dream that this would be that simple! I was under the wrong impression that animated objects could not react in any way with rigid bodies during the time they are animated.