# Rigid body bouncing ball

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have added rigid physics to my object and the floor. The object falls and bounces off the floor. How do I make this happen at a different keyframe? Currently it only does it at the beginning.

Ive clicked animated but I cant work out How I want the ball to fall and bounce at a different keyframe

[image: d]

Comment: You could keyframe (location) the initial position of the ball and then keyframe (location) the starting point of animation. This will keep the ball at the same position till the animation starts.

Comment: Can i add multiple passive bodies to the same active body?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I didn't get your question but a rigid body can only be active or passive and not both.

Comment: I meant... the floor is passive. And lets say ones shoes are passive too. If the ball is active. It will act the same when the ball interacts with the shoes or the floor (bounces in this case)

Comment: I think the ball will be affected by both but I'm not sure. Maybe these will help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1552/54300       https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties.html#rigid-body